# How to disable the marquee tag (text animations) on Mozilla Firefox?

Tags: firefox

I don't want to allow any **<marquee>** tag on Mozilla Firefox.

I have created a new boolean preference in the `about:config` window with the name `browser.display.enable_marquee` and set it to false, but I'm still getting scrolling pieces of text on a web page.

Comment: The equivalent setting in Firefox is [image.animation_mode](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config_entries) (search the page for `animation_`) in [about:config](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config).

Comment: @vWil OP's question was about the scrolling text effected provided by the old marquee tag, and your comment is about disabling animated images. I've posted an answer that solves their problem.

Answer (score 3):

[This old help page](https://web.archive.org/web/20060610031000/http://www.mozilla.org/support/firefox/tips#lay_marquee) has a solution that still works as of March 2015:

1. Open Firefox and press <kbd>ALT</kbd> to show the top menu, then click on `Help` → `Troubleshooting Information` → `Open Containing Folder`
2. If it doesn't exist yet, create a folder named `Chrome`
3. If it doesn't exist yet, create a CSS file with the name `UserContent.css`
4. Copy the following code to `UserContent.css` and restart Firefox:

```
/* Stop those <marquee> tags! */
marquee {
   -moz-binding                  : none !important;
   display                       : block;
   height                        : auto !important;
}
```

Comment: With the TorBrowser you should use the file  `Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Browser/profile.default/chrome/userContent.css` instead.