# Can I make marquees stop scrolling, in my browser?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, html, marquee

While rare these days, some websites, annoyingly, use marquees  (`<marquee>...</marquee>`) - pieces of HTML content scrolling across my browser viewport. This is annoying and distracting.

Is there something I can do to make them stop? I'm using Mozilla Firefox, but answers about Chrome(ium) are also useful.

Bonus points if you can help  me stop a marquee nested within another marquee.

Answer (score 0):

There are CSS-driven solutions in the following answers:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/962509/534406

https://superuser.com/a/886810/215736

If you write a custom userstyle (using Stylish or Stylus, for example) that is active on all websites, then that should work!